# by whom presenting iOS's privacy dialog

Tags: ios, privacy-policy

if my app is requesting GPS location, there's a dialog shown to user asking permission.
and my app also check the authorization, if the user not allow use location service, I will also prompt a dialog to notify user to do the settings.

now the question is, when I `first` launch the app, the user haven't `allow` yet, but the check code also executed, so it will show a dialog beneath the system privacy dialog. now it has two scenarios:

1. user click `Don't allow`, the system dialog dismissed, and my dialog appear, say app don't have permission to locate, that's right.
2. but if user click `Allow`, my will also shown because it's right there, beneath the system's dialog.

I now can only put the two part code different place, but is there a better or more reasonable way to solve this? which is, if user clicked allow, I will know.

some thoughts:
1. if I can know there's a system's privacy dialog been presenting (not a better way, because I just want to know location privacy
2. how to know the location privacy dialog's presenter, so I will use it to check if it has presenting a dialog
3. how to know what action did user do after the privacy dialog is shown can user clicked to dismiss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement **didChangeAuthorizationStatus** delegate method from location manager and check authorization there

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
switch status {
case .NotDetermined:
    // show alert here
    break
case .AuthorizedWhenInUse:

    break
case .AuthorizedAlways:

    break
case .Restricted:
      // show alert here

    break
case .Denied:
      // show alert here
    break
default:
    break
}
}
```

Comment: yeah, seems I ask question too soon and haven't explore the document enough, my bad, I dived into view hierarchy to solved the propblem